# Polar form of Grassmann numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hypercomplex-numbers

How exactly do you write a complex Grassmann number in polar form, or is it not possible? If you construct it by letting the phase be a real number, then you would have something like this $\eta=\rho e^{i\theta}$ with $\rho$ being Grassmann valued. This satisfies the defining property that $\eta^{2}=0$, but the problem is it also seems that $|\eta|^{2}=\rho e^{-i\theta}\rho e^{i\theta}=\rho^{2}=0$ if we demand that $\rho$ is Grassmann. Letting $\theta$ be Grassmann and $\rho$ be real doesn't seem to solve this either, so I suspect it's not even possible. What am I missing?

Comment: What precisely is your definition of a complex Grassmann number?

Comment: @TedShifrin I was thinking of the usual $\eta =a+ib$, with $a,b$ Grassmann.